# How to show different value of input element with ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the controller if have a variable that tracks the index (starting at 0) of the page for a pagination table:

```
var page {
  pageNumber: 0;
}
```

Question: how can I show this `pageNumber` variable in the html, but always incremented by +1? (as the index=0 page is obviously the 1st page and should thus be shown as `Page 1`)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="page.pageNumber">
```

Also, when the model gets updated, the value in the input should automatically change (again: also incremented by +1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is a use-case for $formatters and $parsers. They operate on the model's property and there is no need to create a dummy property on the model. Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). Please correct me if this is not the use case for $formatters and $parsers.

Please see below.

**HTML markup**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">   
   {{page}}
   <input paginated-index type="text" ng-model="page">   
</body>
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.page = 0;
});

app.directive('paginatedIndex', function()
{
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController)
        {
            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(value)
            {
                return value+1;
            })

            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(value)
            {
                return value-1;
            })   
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't know about this mechanism, but it seems to be the correct approach for this type of problems. And works as expected.

Comment: An elegant solution that doesn't involve having extra stuff in the vm

Answer (score 7):

In your controller, change your page object to this:

```
$scope.page = {
  displayedPage: function(num) {
    if(arguments.length) {
       $scope.page.pageNumber = num - 1;
       return num;
    } else {
      return $scope.page.pageNumber + 1;
    }
  },
  pageNumber: 0
}
```

And then yourelement to this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="page.displayedPage" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true}" />
```

This will display the page number plus 1, but leave the actual page.pageNumber variable the way it should be.

The `getterSetter: true` options I've added in will bind the model to a getter/setter function, which allows you to pass in the argument - in this case, your entered page number - and return from that function. You can read more information on this in the documentation for [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Comment: I should have said that I need inverse binding, so the value should be updated in `$scope.page.pageNumber` when the value inside the `input` element changes. Therefore I used `ng-model` as this is handeld automatically.

Comment: So just to be clear - the `<input>` in your original question should display the page number but also be used to change it?

Comment: Yes, the user might be able to change that number. But as the frontend should show the pageindex always incremented by +1, when the user changes this number the value in the model should likewise be decremented -1 to reflect this.

Comment: I don't know what the result of `getterSetter: true` is, but it works. Maybe you could extend your answer and explain this part also for other users?

Comment: It's actually something I learned while answering your question! I've added in my understanding of what the option is doing, but I'm fully prepared to be corrected on it haha

Answer (score 2):

you can try using something like this.

```
   $scope.data=$scope.page.pageNumber+1;
   $scope.fuc=function(){
      $scope.page.pageNumber=$scope.data-1;

   };
```

and your Html will be like

```
    <input type="text"  ng-model="data" ng-change="fuc()" >
```

check this plunk [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/btFr5BrnkyG78fj01l9s?p=preview)