# Angular - How to show selected value different in the input field, different than selected ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ngmodel

Suppose i have

```js
    var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.FDLAccountOther = [{
      "fdlAccountId": 300,
      "fdlAccountName": "IS00698000",
      "fdlAccountDesc": "PT Rebates -To Trading Desks on selling concessions paid to IFG",
      "fdlAccountType": "R",
      "setId": "FDL01",
      "isDefault": null,
      "balanceForward": null,
      "bsIndicator": null,
      "status": "Active"
    }, {
      "fdlAccountId": 301,
      "fdlAccountName": "IS00699000",
      "fdlAccountDesc": "PT Rebates -To Trading Desks on selling concessions paid to IIG",
      "fdlAccountType": "R",
      "setId": "FDL01",
      "isDefault": null,
      "balanceForward": null,
      "bsIndicator": null,
      "status": "Active"
    }]
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="plunker">         
    <div class="input-group" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <input type="text" 
             class="form-control"
             ng-model="formData_TransGrid.fdlAcctNameOther"
             placeholder="Enter FDL Account" 
             uib-typeahead="item.fdlAccountName as item.fdlAccountName for item in FDLAccountOther | filter:$viewValue|limitTo:3" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success ebtn"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="modal" 
                data-target="#FDLAccountLookUp">
          Find FDL 
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
    </html>
```

but as far as input field is concerned i want to show  `item.fdlAccountName + item.fdlAccountDesc + item.status + item.effectiveDate,` once the item is selected. Any way this can be achieved?

### update

ok so now you see when i have  dropdown values when you select 'IS00698000' it shows 'IS00698000' in the input field, which is what you expect, since ng-model binds the value. 
But i want ng-model=formData_TransGrid.fdlAcctNameOther to have value 'IS00698000', but show the user "IS00698000 - PT Rebates -To Trading Desks on selling concessions paid to IFG - Active"

Comment: It's kind of incomplete question for somebody to understand please provide jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: Do you mean you want to show a value in the input once it has focus?

Comment: ok i have added more info

Comment: Your easiest solution is just going to be to display the account details below your INPUT field and just leave the input field to show the account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you should use ng-model getter setter, you can do it like this:

**html:**

```
<input ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true } ng-model="getterSetterFunction" .../>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.getterSetterFunction = function(fdlAcctNameOther) {
    if (fdlAcctNameOther) {
        // set the obj or what ever you like to do..
        $scope.FDLAccountOther.name = fdlAcctNameOther;
    }

    return $scope.FDLAccountOther.fdlAccountName + $scope.FDLAccountOther.fdlAccountDesc + $scope.FDLAccountOther.status + $scope.FDLAccountOther.effectiveDate;
}
```

that just a pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

There are somethings called as formatters and parsers in ngModelController. They are used to convert the values from/to viewModel.
You should use them to solve this problem. Here are some answers related to its implementation which you can use as headsup.

[Angular join multiple fields to one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354267/angular-join-multiple-fields-to-one-field/35355140#35355140)

[How to show different value of input element with ng-model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311780/how-to-show-different-value-of-input-element-with-ng-model/35314930#35314930)

The documentation for them is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)